# Lock screen orientation on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, screen, orientation

Is there a shortcut to lock the screen orientation on the Nexus 4 with android 4.2.1? I read you can swipe down from the top right corner on the Nexus 7 but haven't found any info for the 4.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to `Settings > Display` and then un-check Auto-Rotate. Since that's rather inconvenient, I installed an app called [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc) which makes it possible to force lock the screen orientation to landscape or portrait from the notification bar very easily.

I particularly liked this app since its very lightweight, only about 248kb. It also makes it possible to add single-click actions for things such as the turning on the flashlight or mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

To lock home screen so it would not rotate, just go to launcher settings and disable "rotate screen". That is all you need to do. I am referring to Nexus 4 with OS 4.3
There is nothing is settings that will help. I have been fighting with this for a week not remembering how I did it in the first place..